# How to allow users to add their own custom columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed an asset management system for managing assets, using asp.net mvc4.
Now a new requirement has been raised to allow admin users to add custom records to some assets types. For example we have an asset of type “Vehicles” and they have asked to change(Add/Remove) some columns.  Currently we as developers where managing this by adding the related columns inside the Vehicles DB table and modify the code accordingly. But to allow system user to do so I am planning to do the following:-

1. Inside the DB to create a new table named **Custom_Columns**. With these fields:-

   - ID (Primary Key)
   - name(String)
   - type (String)
   - Type_ID (foreign key to the Asset_Type table)
2. Inside the DB to create a table for storing the **custom_columns_values**, with the following colums:-

   - AssetID (foreign key to the assets table)
   - Cusotme_Column_ID (FK  to the Cusotm_Column) table
   - Value
3. Inside the razor view engine , I will be checking if certain asset have custom columns thorugh its asset_type and display them , or hide the columns if the asset type does not have custom columns.

So in this way the admin can define the custom columns for a certain asset (stored inside the **Cusotm_Columns**)., Then a user can add values to this custom Colum for a certain asset (stored in the **custom_columns_values** table).

Can anyone advice If my approach sound valid or not ? or there can be a better way to manage my custom columns ?

Thanks

Comment: It's a valid way of doing things. Our ERP system does this. This question seems opinion based or more appropriate for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: and do u manage the custom columns in your ERP in a similar way ?